# VS2010: Manifest authoring error c1010097: Element <dependency> missing Key Element: "assemblyIdentity" in the manifest snippet

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, manifest

I could use some help with this sudden problem I got.
Out of nowhere I now get the following error message in VS 2010 when compiling:

manifest authoring error c1010097: Element  missing Key Element: "assemblyIdentity" in the manifest snippet.

But if I open the manifest I can clearly see that there is in fact a section like this:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime" version="2.0.50727.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

I have tried Googling the error code and error message to no avail.
Tried to do a clean on the solution and rebuild, still to no avail.

This has happened in a code branch and if I compare the manifest to production code then WinDiff says the files are identical. I've checked the project settings also, and they are the same too.
The strangest thing is that is says an element is missing from the manifest XML even though it is actually there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, and thought that I will share the solution here.
Turns out there was some differences in the .vcxproj file after all. At the end I found the followin block which gave me the very odd behaviour.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Manifest Include="Setup.exe.manifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Manifest>
  </ItemGroup>
```

What's worse is that I could not find this setting anywhere in the UI-enabled project settings which would affect these lines. So, basically I removed these lines and then it compiles nicely again!